# Can't detect BluetoothLE devices in Win32 C++ console application on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, console-application

I'm trying to work with Bluetooth LE devices using Windows GATT API in Windows 10. But I never detect any devices. Running this code always returns ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS. I've tried with a Windows laptop with built in Bluetooth 4.0 as well as a USB bluetooth dongle.  I see the Bluetooth LE Enumerator in the Device Manager, and the driver shows as installed and working.

Note: I'm trying to build a .dll so I don't want to use UWP.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <SetupAPI.h>
#include <Bluetoothleapis.h>



bool enumDevices() {

    HDEVINFO handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    GUID BluetoothClassGUID = GUID_BLUETOOTHLE_DEVICE_INTERFACE;

    handle = SetupDiGetClassDevs(
        &BluetoothClassGUID,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);

    if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::wcout << "  No Device class" << std::endl;
        return FALSE;
    }

    GUID BluetoothInterfaceGUID = GUID_BLUETOOTHLE_DEVICE_INTERFACE;

    std::vector<SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA> ble_interfaces;
    std::vector<std::wstring> ble_paths;

    // Enumerate device of LE_DEVICE interface class
    for (int i = 0;; i++) {
        std::string error;
        SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA device_interface_data = { 0 };
        device_interface_data.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);
        BOOL success = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(
            handle,
            NULL,
            (LPGUID)&BluetoothInterfaceGUID,
            (DWORD)i,
            &device_interface_data);

        if (!success) {
            DWORD last_error = GetLastError();
            if (last_error == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS) {
                std::wcout << "  No more devices found" << std::endl;
                break;
            }
            else {
                std::wcout << "  Error enumerating device interfaces: " << last_error;
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

        // Retrieve required # of bytes for interface details
        ULONG required_length = 0;
        success = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(
            handle,
            &device_interface_data,
            NULL,
            0,
            &required_length,
            NULL);

        if (!success) {
            DWORD last_error = GetLastError();
            return FALSE;

        }

        UINT8* interface_data = new UINT8[required_length];
        memset(interface_data, 0, required_length);

        PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA device_interface_detail_data = reinterpret_cast<PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA>(interface_data);
        device_interface_detail_data->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

        SP_DEVINFO_DATA device_info_data = { 0 };
        device_info_data.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);

        ULONG actual_length = required_length;
        success = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(
            handle,
            &device_interface_data,
            device_interface_detail_data,
            actual_length,
            &required_length,
            &device_info_data);

        //Store data
        std::wstring strpath = std::wstring(device_interface_detail_data->DevicePath);
        OLECHAR* bstrGuid;
        StringFromCLSID(device_interface_data.InterfaceClassGuid, &bstrGuid);
        std::wcout << "  Path: " << strpath << " GUID:" << bstrGuid << std::endl;
        ble_paths.push_back(strpath);
        ble_interfaces.push_back(device_interface_data);
    }
}


int main() {
    enumDevices();
}
```

Comment: To be able to use this API you must pair your device first. If you need to work with it without pairing use WinRT API. Or third party libs. For example Bluetooth Framework (https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm)

Comment: UWP is not the same as the Windows Runtime. You can consume Windows Runtime types in any DLL, be it a regular DLL or a Windows Runtime component.